# Windows Authentication w/ ASP.NET-IIS7 webpage using WindowsIdentity and CurrentPrincipal

Tags: c#, asp.net

With below entries in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

this line of code

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

returns `NT AUTHORITY\\IUSR`

Without those entries returns: `IIS APPPOOL\\ASP.NET V4.0`

If I use..

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
```

it returns `""`

Also tried to set using..

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
```

on app start. Still the same result `""`.

Am I missing something here ?

I removed impersonate=True and enabled Windows Authemtication Mode in iis and reset iis.
I am getting IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 for identity.name.

This is my is authentication setting.
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: I suggest you activate Windows authentication and disable anonymous access in IIS.

Comment: Tried disabling anonymous access in IIS and activated Win Authemtication. reset iis. Still System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use Windows Authentication to impersonate the user accessing the page? Ie, "DOMAIN\JohnDoe" ?

If so, you need to remove

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

That line causes Windows Authentication to impersonate a Windows User on the IIS server itself. "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" is a system user on your server.

Comment: I have Windows Authentication enabled in iis. But I am not able to get machine name like "DOMAIN\JohnDoe". It returns 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'.

Comment: Did you remove <identity impersonate="true" /> and leave <authentication mode="Windows" /> in your web.config?

Comment: Yes. I removed both entries.

Comment: Don't remove both. Leave  <authentication mode="Windows" /> and remove  <identity impersonate="true" /> (or set it to false).

Comment: Tried. No help. System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name remains empty. FYI: I have only Windows Authentication active under IIS/Authentication

Comment: Just reviewed some code where I do this.. keep the <authentication mode="Windows" /> and remove <identity impersonate="true" /> as I mentioned. However, try using  'HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name' instead of System.Threading

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43153/discussion-between-buffer-overflow-and-bo-tx)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are looking for, but if you just want to see the domain/username connected, I use (vb):

```
dim s as String = Me.User.Identity.Name
```

C# I believe is just

```
string s = this.User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

adding this to web.config resolved the issue.

```
<authorization> 
<deny users="?" /> 
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

- Set Impersonation to true
- Set Windows Authentication to true
- Disable Anonymous

In the code, if you want to get the Domain\User, use the following

```
    System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;     
    String username = User.Identity.Name.ToString()
```

Bonus:
I found the code in the below page to be very useful for tracing Authentication properties

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2013/01/08/asp-net-authentication-test-page.aspx